# what a real mqtt message looks like

Tags: mqtt

I want to publish a message from the device to the mqtt server,but I don't know how to send this message with the correct format, something like json  ?please give me some help to figure out this .Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you do send JSON, then just make sure you know how to parse the JSON back out

Answer (score 2):

There is no "correct format" - MQTT is only a transport, it does not define the payload format.

Answer (score 0):

You can send JSON , String , Integer etc... There is no specific format. Whatever you send you will reach the client which subscribed it.Clients connect to a broker by subscribing and/or publishing to topics and accessing the information.